# How to design Chakra UI useToast by myself?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm learning and using Chakra UI. Chakra UI provides a hook `useToast` to show a toast in the web page. It also provides a component `AlertDialog`, which can show a dialog in the center. I want to create a hook like `useAlertDialog` that can raise a dialog like this:

```js
const dialog = useAlertDialog({ some options ... });

return (
  <Button onClick={dialog}>Open the dialog</Button>
)
```

I tried to use `ReactDOM.createPortal`, but it did not work. I did some research, and the reason seems to be that the component I create in `createPortal` still has to be inserted in the node tree. Then I tried to understand how Chakra UI implements the function, but I didn't find the source code. All I know is that it uses provider and context hook.

Can anyone tell me how to implement `useAlertDialog` hook, or how Chakra UI implements `useToast` hook? I do NOT want to insert any component to the node tree manually.

P.S. It would be nice if I can specify a callback function called when the dialog is closed.